# How to run a java program in php xampp

Tags: java, php, xampp, exec

Firstly, should it be a jar file or a Java file ... secondly, where to place the file exactly if I am using xampp... I found lots of example on exec, shell_exec..but nothing worked.. i tried both as a jar file and as java file .. nothing is working literally ... i tried placing it in the xampp folder and in the bin in the program files of the java folder ... but it didn't work ... is there any include statement before the exec command i should do .. i tried with the full directory path but it didnt work as well..any help with an example is appreciated

```
<?php

  $file = __DIR__ . '/../xampp/htdocs/test.jar';

 exec('java'.$file, $output);
 print_r($output);


 ?>
```

The above code shows an empty array...

Comment: What type of java program are you trying to run from PHP?  Is it a cli utility?

Comment: for now i am just testing a simple class with a main and print .. but when it works i will be doing encryption ... 
public class Test {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 System.out.println(" AWESOME! :) ");
}
}

Comment: In order for exec or shell_exec to work, your Java program would need to be executable.  PHP won't read another language's class.

Comment: You need a JDK to run the Java file against.  XAMPP does not include such a JDK.  I would expect you to include your Java classes in a WAR file and deploy on a Java server such as Tomcat.  You could then configure your Apache HTTP Server as reverse proxy for the Tomcat server.

Comment: @Devon ok so it should be a jar file ... do i need to place it in a specific path?

Comment: Install JDK into your system, run your .jar with exec / shell_exec (prefer him) and take the output of your jar.

It's important to test before your shell execution if java exists with a php exec with which.

Answer (score -1):

First of all XAMPP is a Web server stack using Apache / PHP / MySQL. It has nothing to do with Java. You CAN execute compiled Java programs from within PHP, but for this, your Java program needs to be compiled to bytecode already (using `javac`), and you need a working JRE on your XAMPP installation.

Then it is just a matter of execute java as an external process from within PHP:

```
<?php
$ret = exec('java -cp path/to/your/java/program Test')
?>
```

or similar.

Comment: if my jar file is called test.jar and is placed inside the xampp folder in htdocs .. my code should be  <?php $ret = exec('java -cp xampp/htdocs/test.jar Test)?> .. is this right?

Comment: You are going to create a maintenance nightmare like this.  Put your Java code on a Java server.  Do not embed it in exec scripts that are tightly coupled with your environment and will break with the slightest change to it.

Comment: It depends on your jarfile. You can also use `java -jar test.jar`, but then your jar file needs a Manifest file.
And, as the commenter before noted: Why do you want to mix PHP and Java code? Could the program you plan not be implemented in PHP?

Comment: @AlexSchenkel we are trying to implement Elliptic Curve Cryptography and we could only find one library in php which is not well documented.. after wasting a lot of time on it .. we decided to try our working java code in php ..

Comment: @AlexSchenkel nothing worked .. it gives me Parse error Syntax Error unexpected java(T_String)

Comment: Sorry I cannot help here - I think you basically first have to learn the basics of Java, PHP and the core concepts around them.